# plotting a histogram in julia with as many bins as values

Tags: plot, julia

How do I make Julia Plots with the Plotly backend give me a histogram with as many integer bins from 0 to max value in the series while displaying all the x-axis tick marks for each bin?

```
using Plots
plotly()
age = 100*rand(1000,1)
histogram(age, bins=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but only if you resize the plot from the default, else your x axis label numbers will overlap.

```
julia> nbins = Int(floor(maximum(age) - minimum(age) + 1))
100

julia> histogram(age, bins=nbins, tickmode = :auto, xticks = nbins, size = 
(1600, 1000))
```

[example of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8f8w.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Julia exactly what the bins should be.

```
using Plots

age = 100*rand(1000,1)
bins = floor(minimum(age)):1:ceil(maximum(age))
# Range with step size 1. The values are floored/ceiled so the bins are actual integers.

histogram(  age, bins=bins, xticks=bins,
            xrotation = 90, size = (1200,1200)) # to make it more readable
```